# jquery animated menu opens but won't close

Tags: jquery

I have a mobile menu that currently animates open from the right edge of the viewport when the hamburger is clicked. But a subsequent click of the hamburger does nothing. It *should* animate the menu to the closed position. I've tried many variations of the following without success.

```
$('#menu-wrap').prepend('<div id="menu-trigger"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></div>');
$("#menu-trigger").on("click", function(){
    $('this').addClass('opened');
    $('#menu').animate({ width:'220' }, 500).css('padding', '40px');        
});
$("#menu-trigger.opened").on("click", function(){
    $('this').removeClass('opened');
    $('#menu').animate({ width:'0' }, 500).css('padding', '0px');
});
```

I've verified that #menu-trigger does receive the class 'opened', but it doesn't respond after the first click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both click events will still fire because you're not telling the first one not to fire in any way. That might cause issues with what really happens.

Consider rewriting that code to something more clear, like this:

```
$("#menu-trigger").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('opened'){
    $(this).removeClass('opened');
    $('#menu').animate({ width:'0' }, 500).css('padding', '0px');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('opened');
    $('#menu').animate({ width:'220' }, 500).css('padding', '40px');        
  }
});
```

Also, `$('this')` and `$(this)` are not the same - the former will look for elements with tag name `this` in the DOM (like `<this></this>`) which is not what you want.

---

```js
$("#menu-trigger").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
    $(this).removeClass('opened');
    $('#menu').animate({
      width: '0'
    }, 500).css('padding', '0px');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('opened');
    $('#menu').animate({
      width: '220'
    }, 500).css('padding', '40px');
  }
});
```

```css
#menu-trigger {color: red}
#menu-trigger.opened {color: green}
#menu {border: 1px solid black; display: inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="menu-trigger">Menu trigger</button><br>
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
```